# How does $\cot(t)^3 \dfrac{-3\tan(t)+\tan(2t)}{3\cot(t)+\tan(2t)}$ simplify to $-\cot(3t)$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cot(t)^3 \times \dfrac{-3\tan(t)+\tan(2t)}{3\cot(t)+\tan(2t)}$$

The expression above apparently simplifies to $-\cot(3t)$. How can this be shown?

Comment: As the saying goes: *What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?* ... Have you considered expanding $\cos(3t)$ and $\sin(3t)$ and seeing if you can manipulate the numerator and denominator of the given expression into related forms?

Comment: I've only got the LHS to work with, not the answer $-\cot(3t)$

Comment: *I've only got the LHS to work with, not the answer* ... Okay, so start with the given expression. In the absence of some keen insight about tangents and cotangents (which I lack in this case), you can start with the standard strategy of writing everything in terms of sines and cosines, and see where that takes you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\eqalign{
  & E = {\cot ^3}\left( x \right)\frac{{\tan \left( {2x} \right) - 3\tan \left( x \right)}}{{\tan \left( {2x} \right) + 3\cot \left( x \right)}} = {\cot ^3}\left( x \right)\frac{{\tan \left( x \right)\left( {\tan \left( {2x} \right) - 3\tan \left( x \right)} \right)}}{{\tan \left( x \right)\tan \left( {2x} \right) + 3}} = {\cot ^2}\left( x \right)\frac{{\tan \left( {2x} \right) - 3\tan \left( x \right)}}{{\tan \left( x \right)\tan \left( {2x} \right) + 3}}  \cr 
  & \tan \left( {2x} \right) = \frac{{2\tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}} \Rightarrow \tan \left( {3x} \right) = \tan \left( {2x + x} \right) = \frac{{\tan \left( {2x} \right) + \tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - \tan \left( {2x} \right)\tan \left( x \right)}} = \frac{{\frac{{2\tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}} + \tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - \frac{{2\tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}}\tan \left( x \right)}} = \frac{{3\tan \left( x \right) - {{\tan }^3}\left( x \right)}}{{ - 3{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) + 1}}  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow  - \tan \left( {3x} \right) = \frac{{3\tan \left( x \right) - {{\tan }^3}\left( x \right)}}{{3{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) - 1}}  \cr 
  & E = {\cot ^2}\left( x \right)\frac{{\frac{{2\tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}} - 3\tan \left( x \right)}}{{\tan \left( x \right)\frac{{2\tan \left( x \right)}}{{1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}} + 3}} = {\cot ^2}\left( x \right)\frac{{2\tan \left( x \right) - 3\tan \left( x \right)\left( {1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)}}{{2{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) + 3\left( {1 - {{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)}} =  - {\cot ^2}\left( x \right)\frac{{3{{\tan }^3}\left( x \right) - \tan \left( x \right)}}{{{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) - 3}}  \cr 
  &  =  - \frac{{3{{\tan }^3}\left( x \right) - \tan \left( x \right)}}{{{{\tan }^4}\left( x \right) - 3{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right)}} =  - \frac{{3{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) - 1}}{{{{\tan }^3}\left( x \right) - 3\tan \left( x \right)}} = \frac{{3{{\tan }^2}\left( x \right) - 1}}{{3\tan \left( x \right) - {{\tan }^3}\left( x \right)}} =  - \frac{1}{{\tan \left( {3x} \right)}} =  - \cot \left( {3x} \right) \cr} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot^3t \times \frac{-3\tan t + \tan {2t}}{3\cot t + \tan {2t}} = \cot^3t \times \frac{\frac{-3}{\cot t} + \frac{1}{\cot 2t}}{3\cot t + \frac{1}{\cot 2t}} =$$ $$=\cot^3t \times \frac{\frac{-3}{\cot t}+\frac{2\cot t}{\cot^2 t - 1}}{3\cot t + \frac{2\cot t}{\cot^2 t - 1}} =$$ $$= \cot^3t \times \frac{\frac{3-\cot^2 t}{\cot t (\cot^2 t - 1)}}{\frac{3\cot^3 t - \cot t}{\cot^2 t - 1}} =$$ $$= \cot t \times \frac{3-\cot^ 2 t}{3cot^2 t - 1} = \frac{3\cot t - \cot^3}{3\cot^2 t -1} = -\cot {3t}$$

Here
$$\cot 2t =\frac{\cos 2t}{\sin 2t}=\frac{\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t}{2\sin t \cos t}=\frac{cot^2 t - 1}{2\cot t}$$

$$\cot 3t=\cot (2t+t)=\frac{\cot 2t \times \cot t - 1}{\cot 2t + \cot t}=\frac{\cot^3 t - 3\cot t}{3\cot^2 t - 1}$$

Comment: Wow, so alright — quick question: how did you know that you had to do what you did? See, for me, it seems quite random that you knew that $\frac{1}{\cot(2t)}$ needed to be converted to $\frac{2\cot t}{\cot^2 {t}-1}$. If it's just intuition, then that's very impressive!